# What do the ideas do?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In Chapter Two, when summoning my first new blade I noticed that when summoning a blade, four ideas are show which are:

- Bravery
- Truth
- Compassion
- Justice

These ideas seem to be directly related to summoning blades and can be increased temporarily. right before summoning them. However, I don't know how they affect the blade produced.

What do these ideas do when summoning a blade?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing an idea increases the base statistic for that character. So, if you increase Justice, then your Justice level goes up which will increase the chance of getting a Blade with the two elements that correspond with Justice.

Ideas also increase the probability of getting a rare blade.

Answer (score 0):

Each idea corresponds to a pair of opposing elements;

- Bravery - Fire / Water
- Truth - Wind / Ice
- Compassion - Earth / Lightning
- Justice - Dark / Light

When you bond a new blade their element is determined by the ideas of the character you are bonding with. Though having one idea higher than the others doesn't actually guarantee getting a blade with the elements associated with that idea, it just makes it more likely.

A character's ideas increase when you unlock some new parts of a Blade's affinity chart (rare blades mainly though I think some less rare blades also have affinity unlocks which affect ideas), this is shown in the top right corner of an ability's description box if an idea is increased when it unlocks.